# Make the difference between a file path and a url in Qt

Tags: qt, qurl

If I have a string which could be either a **file** or a **URL**, is there any existing clever method I could use to differentiate them?

For instance:

- /Users/user/Documents/mydoc.txt -> path
- c:\Program Files\myapp\mydoc.doc -> path
- https://mywebsite.com/mydoc.txt -> url
- ftp://myserver.com/myfile.txt -> url

This is to load a designer UI file, so I need to make a local temporary copy of the remote file.
So the bottom line is to know when I need to download the file.

Comment: Could you bring an example?

Comment: example added in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you might want to construct a `QUrl` object out of these strings and verify whether these URLs refer to local files. I.e.:

```
static bool isLocalFile(const QString &str)
{
    return QUrl::fromUserInput(str).isLocalFile();
}
```

With your strings

```
QString s1("/Users/user/Documents/mydoc.txt");
QString s2("c:\\Program Files\\myapp\\mydoc.doc");
QString s3("https://mywebsite.com/mydoc.txt");
QString s4("ftp://myserver.com/myfile.txt");

bool b = isLocalFile(s1); // a path
b = isLocalFile(s2); // a path
b = isLocalFile(s3); // not a path
b = isLocalFile(s4); // not a path
```

Comment: Yes, this one is actually better

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `QFile` with the given name and check if it `exists()`. If not try to resolve string as a URL.